# DB2 query with subqueries and multiple group by statements

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I've got a query that has multiple subqueries and conditions to build calculated columns each with their own grouping.

The problem is, Something is either not joined or grouped right and I'm not able to get the right values across all rows. I'm selecting the raw rows for the last 90 days but my calculations are only based on the records in the last 30 days.

```
SELECT
  t.dealer,
  t.rep,
  t.group,
  t.dtl1,
  t.dtl2,
  t.quant,
  temp.sales as V1,
  tmng.sales as V2,
  tall.sales as V3
FROM
     products t
    left outer JOIN (
        SELECT dealer,group,dtl1,dtl2, SUM(cast(quant as int)) as sales
        FROM products
        WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
        GROUP BY dealer,group,dtl1,dtl2
    ) temp ON temp.dealer = t.dealer and temp.group = t.group and temp.dtl1 = t.dtl1 and temp.dtl2 = t.dtl2
    left outer JOIN (
        SELECT sales_rep, group,dtl1,dtl2, SUM(cast(quant as int)) as sales
        FROM products
        WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
        GROUP BY sales_rep,group,dtl1,dtl2
    ) tmng ON  tmng.sales_rep = t.sales_rep AND tmng.group = t.group AND tmng.dtl1 = t.dtl1 and tmng.dtl2 = t.dtl2
    left outer JOIN (
        SELECT dealer, sales_rep, group,dtl1,dtl2,SUM(cast(quant as int)) as sales
        FROM products
        WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
        group by dealer,sales_rep, group,dtl1,dtl2
    ) tall on tall.dealer = t.dealer and tall.sales_rep = t.sales_rep and  tall.group = t.group and tall.dtl1 = t.dtl1 and tall.dtl2 = t.dtl2

WHERE t.last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 90 DAYS;
```

The idea is that a product is unique by Group/Dtl1/Dtl2. So if I query on a single product (with that unique combo) I get the specific total quantity per row but what I need to resolve is my last three columns, where I need the sum of 'qty' for the last 30 days for the dealer, the rep and total.

Right now I get the correct number of rows, but spotty values and null values in my last three columns.

```
Dealer | Rep   | Group  | Dtl1   | Dtl2 | qty |   V1  |   V2    |  V3
========================================================================
21177  |  165  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
19445  |  182  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
20949  |  340  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  2  |  null  |  null  |  null
21347  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
23068  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
17195  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  6  |  null  |  null  |  null
23040  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
5620   |  380  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  4  |  null  |  null  |  null
23009  |  380  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  3  |  null  |  null  |  null
13529  |  390  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
22706  |  394  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1     |  1     |  1
17049  |  394  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  4  |  1     | null   | null 
17879  |  397  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
21320  |  445  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  null  |  null  |  null
21231  |  457  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1     |  1     |  1
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
Dealer | Rep   | Group  | Dtl1   | Dtl2 | qty | V1  | V2  |  V3
================================================================
21177  |  165  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
19445  |  182  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
20949  |  340  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  2  |  2  |  2  |  29
21347  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  9  |  29
23068  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  9  |  29
17195  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  6  |  6  |  9  |  29
23040  |  353  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  9  |  29
5620   |  380  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  4  |  4  |  7  |  29
23009  |  380  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  3  |  3  |  7  |  29
13529  |  390  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
22706  |  394  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  5  |  29
17049  |  394  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  4  |  4  |  5  |  29 
17879  |  397  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
21320  |  445  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
21231  |  457  |  4867  |  2878  |  29  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  29
```

So V1 is the sum of qty for the Dealer/group/dtl1/dtl2 for the last 30 days, V2 is the sum of qty for the Rep/Group/Dtl1/Dtl2 for the last 30 days, and V3 is the TOTAL sum of (qty) for that Group/Dtl1/Dtl2 for the last 30 days.

WHat am I doint wrong?

Here's the fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22251a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (DEALER, REP, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2, QUANT, LAST_SHIP_DATE) AS (
VALUES  (21177, 165, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (19445, 182, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (20949, 340, 4867, 2878, 29, 2, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21347, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23068, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17195, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 6, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23040, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (5620,  380, 4867, 2878, 29, 4, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23009, 380, 4867, 2878, 29, 3, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (13529, 390, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (22706, 394, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17049, 394, 4867, 2878, 29, 4, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17879, 397, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21320, 445, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21231, 457, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY)
      , (1, 1, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, CURRENT DATE - 100 DAY)
)
SELECT T.DEALER, T.REP, T.GROUP, T.DTL1, T.Dtl2, T.QUANT
/*
, SUM(CASE WHEN last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS THEN QUANT END) OVER(PARTITION BY DEALER, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2) V1
, SUM(CASE WHEN last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS THEN QUANT END) OVER(PARTITION BY REP,    GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2) V2
, SUM(CASE WHEN last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS THEN QUANT END) OVER(PARTITION BY         GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2) V3
FROM T;
*/
, COALESCE(T1.V1, 0) V1, COALESCE(T2.V2, 0) V2, COALESCE(T3.V3, 0) V3
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DEALER, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2, SUM(QUANT) V1
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY DEALER, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2
) T1 ON T1.DEALER=T.DEALER AND T1.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T1.DTL1=T.DTL1 AND T1.DTL2=T.DTL2
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT REP, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2, SUM(QUANT) V2
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY REP, GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2
) T2 ON T2.REP=T.REP AND T2.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T2.DTL1=T.DTL1 AND T2.DTL2=T.DTL2
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2, SUM(QUANT) V3
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY GROUP, DTL1, Dtl2
) T3 ON T3.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T3.DTL1=T.DTL1 AND T3.DTL2=T.DTL2;
```

Comment: I tried partitions earlier with no luck, potentially because of my db2 version (iseries db2 7..2) but I'll try this. Is there an alternative doing what you're doing but without the partition?

Comment: As I was afraid, I just tried it but it says it doesn't expect '(', only FROM or INTO

Comment: I've changed the example. OLAP SUM function is supported in DB2 for IBM i since 7.3.

Comment: I believe that got it actually, but is there not a way for me to divide the SUM by another value without grouping on it too? Say I wanted to take the whole sum line and divide it by another column

Comment: I didn't get the question. Can you provide some example on what you want to achieve?

Comment: BTW, you should tag your post with the `db2-400` tag to specify, that you work with db2 for IBM i...

Comment: I may need to think it through but I'm wondering if I wanted to take the SUM(case etc.) and do SUM()/COLUMN, would I have to add the new column to the grouping. Also, can I ask what the addition of coalesce will do here?

Comment: In case of `SUM()/COLUMN` - yes, `COLUMN` must be in the `group by` clause. As for `coalesce`: Outer join may return no rows for some record in the inner table. If you don't want to see `null` in the corresponding column, the `coalesce` function returns 0 in such a case.

Comment: I'm trying to currently divide each of the SUM() by a column and I'm adding the column in a group by but it doesn't seem to be working quite as expected. Should the column be in the GROUP as well as the ON?